# Maximum of three numbers in C

Tags: c

I have three numbers, m, n and p. I am trying to find the maximum using nested if..else if..else.

Here is my code for the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    float m,n,p;
    scanf("%f%f%f", &m,&n,&p);
    if(m>n){
        if(m>p){
            printf("%f",m);
        }
    }
    else if(n>p){
        if(n>m){
            printf("%f",n);
            }
        }
    else{   
        printf("%f",p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I input m=4,n=2,p=11. It doesn't print anything!
Shouldn't last else statement be working and giving the result as 11?

Comment: Step through the program with your debugger.

Comment: .. or use some logging (say with `printf`). At least *try* to [debug it somehow](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I am not really sure how do I debug it, I tried to write printf and check, but apparently the code never enters last else statement if n is the smallest and p is the largest.
Does the last else I am using correspond to the first if?

Comment: The task required is to find max of three numbers, but I was just fiddling around the code and trying to do it this way. Apparently its not working.

Comment: "Shouldn't last else statement be working and giving the result as 11?" --> 4 > 2 is true, so code enters the `if()` body: `if(m>n){
        if(m>p){
            printf("%f",m);
        }
    }`  Then `m > p` is not true, so nothing prints - why is that unexpected?

Comment: No.  After the `if()` block is **entered** (the `if` is true), code does that block and then does the code after `else{   
        printf("%f",p);
    }` which is `return 0;`

Comment: I understand it now! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `else`s only apply to the previous `if`, nesting `if` statements is not working the way you intend, instead you should be using the "and" operator to check if the two conditions are true in the same `if`. Additionally you want to check with `>=` not just `>` in case the two largest numbers are equal.

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    float m,n,p;
    scanf("%f%f%f", &m,&n,&p);
    if(m >= n && m >= p){
        printf("%f",m);
    } else if(n >= p && n >= m) {
        printf("%f",n);
    } else{   
        printf("%f",p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

for a simpler example, if you had code like this:

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        printf("first\n");
    }
} else {
    print("second\n");
}
```

The `else` is only related to whether `a` is true or false. If you had `a = true` and `b = false` the above would print nothing. Your program would enter the `if (a)` body (so the `else` never runs), then see `if (b)` and skip `printf("first\n")` before exiting.

Answer (score 9):

Simplify your code by moving the logic of finding the maximum to a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float max_of_two(float x, float y)
{
   return (x > y) ? x : y;
}

float max_of_three(float m, float n, float p)
{
   return max_of_two(max_of_two(m, n), p);
}

int main()
{
    float m,n,p;
    scanf("%f%f%f", &m,&n,&p);
    printf("%f", max_of_three(m, n, p));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A late answer. This simple solution does not need any nesting of conditionals:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float m, n, p, max;
    if(scanf("%f%f%f", &m, &n, &p) != 3) {
        puts("Bad input");
        return 1;
    }
    max = m; 
    if(n > max) {
        max = n;
    }
    if(p > max) {
        max = p;
    }
    printf("%f", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a silly macro

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define mo3(m,n,p) ( (m) > (n) ? ((m) > (p) ? (m) : (p)) : ((n) > (p) ? (n) : (p)))

int main(void) {

int m=4,n=2,p=11;
     // your code goes here
     printf("%d\n", mo3(m,n,p));
     return 0;
 }
```

https://ideone.com/0El8nX

Answer (score 0):

#### NAN

A variation on [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761434/2410359) answer using floating point math and handles [Not a Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) well:

When NaN are present, the usual handling of them is to disregard their presence.  Thus the `max5(-2.0, NAN, -1.0, NAN, -3.0)` is `-1.0`.

```
double max3(double a, double b, double c) {
  double mx = -INFINITY;
  bool found = false;
  if (a >= mx) {
    mx = a;
    found = true;
  }
  if (b >= mx) {
    mx = b;
    found = true;
  }
  if (c >= mx) {
    mx = c;
    found = true;
  }
  return found ? mx : NAN;
}
```

The above uses a very common, though not C specified behavior, of `<, <=, >=, >` comparing a NAN with a number is the result is false.  When `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined with the value of 1, this desired compare result is specified behavior.

An alternative to `#if __STDC_IEC_559__ == 1` could use the `isnan()` macro.

Of course another functionality could return NAN if any of the numbers are NAN.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    float m,n,p;
    scanf("%f %f %f", &m,&n,&p);
    if(m>n){
        if(m>p){
            printf("%f",m);
        }
        else{
          printf("%f", p);
        }
    }
    else if(n>p){
          printf("%f", n);
         }
    else{
      printf("%f", p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for all cases. Test it with inputs of `1 2 3` and you will see no output.

Comment: Hi I have edited just now. Last else clause was missing.