# How can I improve the program to find the largest number among three numbers?

Tags: c, conditional-statements, max

Although I have written a code for this problem, I don't think it's quite short and appropriate.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    float a, b, c;
    printf("Enter ");
    printf("\na: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("b: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("c: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    if (a == b && a == c) {
        printf("All are equal");
    }
    else if (a == b & a > c) {
        printf("%f is greatest", a);
    }
    else if (a == b & a < c) {
        printf("%f is greatest",c);
    }
    else if (a == c & a < b) {
        printf("%f is greatest", b);
    }
    else if (a == c & a > b) { 
        printf("%f is greatest", a);
    }
    else if (b == c & b < a) { 
        printf("%f is greatest", a);
    }
    else if (b == c & b > a) {
        printf("%f is greatest", b);
    }
    else if (a > b && a >= c) {
        printf("%f is the greatest", a);
    }
    else if (b > a && b > c) {
        printf("%f is the greatest", b);
    }
    else if (c > a && c > b) {
        printf("%f is the greatest", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I shorten the code and make it more readable, using only conditionals statements?

Comment: You don't need all the checks for equality. If `a < b` and `b < c` then `c` is largest. Rotate the variables and get all three possible variations.

Comment: Checking if one is greater than or equal to the other two is enough to tell you that value is the greatest.  Then do the same for the other two.

Comment: Maybe `a >= b && a >= c` then print 'a' and rotate

Comment: See the duplicate question. And you should really learn how to properly format your code.

Comment: Does _Using only conditionals._ mean that you _can't_ put the vars in an array and loop over them? If so, this seems like a test of nested conditionals rather than a general algorithm for finding the maximum of N values? A loop would be simpler logic.

Comment: If you have working code that you want peer reviewed for improvement, your question belongs on [codereview.se], which was created specifically for that purpose. This site is for **specific questions** related to actual problems you're having with code or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). For more information, see the [help].

Answer (score 2):

**@klutt** closed this question as duplicated.

[Maximum of three numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761187/maximum-of-three-numbers-in-c)

But I looked through the provided reference to the similar question and was not satisfied.

First of all the answers that are present in the provided reference to the similar question ignore entirely the case when all three numbers are equal each other. For example in some answers there is used a function or a macro that determines the maximum value but the both are not suitable to determine that all three numbers are equal each other. But in the original question in this case there must be outputed an appropriate message.

Also it will be interesting to point to the name of the exact number a, b, or c that is greater than others. For example if a is equal to b and the both are greater than c then in the original question there is outputed the number a. To make it clear the name of the variable a should be present in the output.

I can suggest the following silution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    float a, b, c;

    printf( "Enter " );
    printf( "\na: " );
    scanf( "%f", &a );
    printf( "b: " );
    scanf( "%f", &b );
    printf( "c: " );
    scanf( "%f", &c );

    if ( a == b && b == c )
    {
        puts( "All are equal" );
    }
    else if ( !( a < b ) && !( a < c ) )
    {
        printf( "a equal to %f is greatest.\n", a );
    }
    else if ( !( b < c ) )
    { 
        printf( "b equal to %f is greatest.\n", b );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "c equal to %f is greatest.\n", c );
    }
}
```

Of course it would be desirable to add a check that the input of three numbers was correct.

Comment: The question was about the maximum number (value), not the variable name. Als the case of "all equal" should not get a special treatment.

Comment: @harper But if you will look through the question when there is outputed a if a and b are equal each other, or there is outputed b if b and c are equal each other. So it is interesting to point to the exact name of the variable that is greatest. Also in the similar question there is entirely ignored the case when all three variables are equal each other while in the original question in this case there must be outputed a message.

Answer (score 2):

If you create just one additional function, this becomes much simpler:

```
float max(float x, float y) {
    return x >= y ? x : y;
}
```

Now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float a, b, c;

    printf("Enter\n");
    printf("a: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("b: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("c: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    if (a == b && b == c) {
        printf("All are equal\n");
    }
    else {
        float m = max(max(a, b), c);
        printf("%f is the greatest\n", m);
    }
}
```

Where that is equivalent to:

```
    else {
        float t = a >= b ? a : b;
        float m = t >= c ? t : c; 
        printf("%f is the greatest\n", m);
    }
```

Or avoiding the ternary expression:

```
    else {
        float t;
        float m;

        if (a >= b) t = a;
        else t = b;

        if (t >= c) m = t;
        else m = c;
 
        printf("%f is the greatest\n", m);
    }
```

Comment: Minor Printing with `"%g"` is more informative the `"%f"` for small values and less noisy for large ones.

Answer (score 0):

Given 3 numbers and trying to find:

1. If all equal, report that all are equal.
2. Else print the greatest value.

> How can I shorten the code ...?

OP's approach, in the worst case, does many compare.  Even other answers perform up to  4 compares..

I assert it takes, at most 3 compares among `a,b,c`, (assuming none are [NAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)).

```
if (a == b) {
  if (b == c) printf("All are equal");
  else if (a > c) printf("%f is greatest", a);
  else printf("%f is greatest", c);
} else {
  if (a > b) {
    if (a > c) printf("%f is greatest", a);
    else printf("%f is greatest", c);
  else {
    if (b > c) printf("%f is greatest", b);
    else printf("%f is greatest", c);
  }
}
```